# How to save sidenav (mat-drawer) state to localstorage in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template, mat-sidenav, mat-drawer

I have problem with mat-drawer in Angular Material. I want to save my state to localstorage but mat-drawer is always opened.

Sidenav have expanded part and closed expanded part when stay mat-icons without text. When you click on bottom button Hide, the sidenav is Close but after refresh page Sidenav is again expanded (but in the localstorage is close).

**Looks like this:**

**[Opened expanded mat drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/busRU.png)**

**[Closed mat drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M1Fm.png)**

**[Sidenav is open but in local storage is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aITB.png)**

Do you know how resolve this thing? Thank you!

**Source code:**

app.component.html

```
<mat-drawer-container class="content-container" autosize >
 <mat-drawer
  mode="side"
  class="sidenav"
  disableClose="true"
  opened="true">
<div class="sidenav-container">
<mat-nav-list>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item routerLink="/private/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
        <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;"  matTooltipPosition="right" [matTooltipDisabled]="disabledTooltip">dashboard</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Dashboard</span>
      </a>

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item routerLink="/private/companies" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">stars</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Subjects</span>
      </a>

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item routerLink="/private/users" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">group</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Users</span>
      </a>

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item routerLink="/private/api-customers" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">beenhere</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Clients</span>
      </a>

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item routerLink="/private/applications" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">apps</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Apps</span>
      </a>

      <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item routerLink="/private/calendar" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon style="padding-right:5px;">calendar_today</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Calendar</span>
      </a>
</mat-nav-list>
        <div class="sidenav-bottom">
          <mat-nav-list>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" mat-list-item (click)="onSidenavToggle()">
              <mat-icon *ngIf="isExpanded">arrow_back_ios</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon *ngIf="!isExpanded">arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
              <span *ngIf="isExpanded">Hide</span>
            </a>
          </mat-nav-list>
        </div>
    </mat-drawer>
<mat-drawer-content>
Page content
</mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, HostListener, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent  {

  isExpanded = true;
  constructor(
  private sidenavService: SidebarService) {
  this.sidenavService.setHideSidebar(this.sidenavService.isHideSidebar());
  }
  onSidenavToggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
    this.sidenavService.setHideSidebar(!this.sidenavService.isHideSidebar());
    this.sidenavService.sideBarState$.next(this.isExpanded);
  }}
```

sidebar.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {

  public sideBarState$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    const initialValue = localStorage.getItem('isExpanded');
    this.sideBarState$.next(initialValue === 'close');
  }

  getHideSidebar(): Subject<boolean> {
    return this.sideBarState$;
  }

  setHideSidebar(newValue: boolean): void {
    localStorage.setItem('isExpanded', newValue ? 'close' : 'open');
    this.sideBarState$.next(newValue);
  }

  isHideSidebar(): boolean {
    return localStorage.getItem('isExpanded') === 'close';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is with your `isExpanded` in the component. The value is being hard coded to `true` and has nothing to do with the service (or the value stored in LOCALSTORAGE).

Some other suggestions are to use the `Subject` value alone as the one true source of what `isExpanded` should be (Use the EMIT value, do not set it up yourself). Also it would make more sense if you store `isExpanded` as true or false, instead of `open` or `close`. The variable name suggests the value to be a true or false.

```
import {Component, HostListener, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})

export class AppComponent  {

  isExpanded;
  constructor(
  private sidenavService: SidebarService) {
  isExpanded = !this.sidenavService.isHideSidebar();
  }
  onSidenavToggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
    this.sidenavService.setHideSidebar(!this.sidenavService.isHideSidebar());
    this.sidenavService.sideBarState$.next(this.isExpanded);
  }}
```